# Выгрузить табличку ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли как-то выгрузить таблицу из бд в MS SQL в виде запроса или какого-то файлика, чтобы можно было восстановить, к примеру, в этой же бд?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15 Есть встроенный генератор скриптов на создание и на заполнение таблицы

Comment: я так делал, он только табличку создает без данных, может упустил что-то?

Comment: Там рядом с созданием скрипта на CREATE есть пункт создания скрипта на INSERT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение с генерацией скрипта в SSMS:

1. Правой кнопкой мыши по базе
2. Задачи -> Сформировать скрипты..
3. Из списка выбираешь свою таблицу(ы), выбираешь "Открыть в новом окне запроса"
4. На этой же странице жмёшь кнопку "Дополнительно" и в параметре "Тип данных для внесения в скрипт" выбираешь значение "схема и данные" и жмёшь 2 раза "Далее"

В итоге у тебя будет скрипт создания таблицы и вставки данных для каждой строки. Пробуй.

Comment: Круто! текст запроса есть, пока не пересоздавал, но уверен что все работает, спасибо за подробную инструкцию!